# Is it possible to compare the generated reports from SSRS and Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I've migrated our company reports from Crystal to SSRS. I'm wondering if there exists a way to perform automatic quality assurance test on the newly implemented reporting service against the running Crystal reports? Since both solutions drain from the same data-source, we're concern about the correctness of the data (including raw and computed). Please kindly advise.

Thanks & regards,
William Choi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need some tool that would be able to parse both sets of reports and compare.
The only way I can imagine would be if both could be exported to excel and compared there.

But I doubt that is going to work all that well, based on my limited experience of exporting Crystal reports.